# Create list of numbers mirrored around zero (python)

Tags: python, list, numpy

I think this should be a simple question... but it's been holding me up for some time now :(

I wish to create a list of numbers, centred (as it were) on zero, from an input that specifies the maximum and the increment. So,

```
max = 100
increment = 1
```

would return

```
[-100,-99,-98,...,-1,0,1,...,99,100]
```

and

```
max = 35
increment = 0.2
```

would return

```
[-35.0,-34.8,...,-0.2,0,0.2,...34.8,35.0]
```

If the increment doesn't divide neatly into the maximum, it needs to make a short last step (e.g. if counting to 1 in 0.3 increments, it would run `[-1.0,-0.6,-0.3,0.0,0.3,0.6,0.9,1.0]`

`list(numpy.linspace())` seems to be the way to go but I seem to be having a complete mental block on how to make this work in the way described for anything but the simplest cases.

Suggestions appreciated!

edit: my own solution was

```
def mylist(stop,step):
    a = list(np.arange(0,-stop,-step))+[-stop]
    a.reverse()
    b = list(a)
    c = list(np.arange(0,stop,step))+[stop]
    d = b+c
    d.remove(0)
    e = list(d)
    return e
```

which is horribly clunky, even I can see.

The best answer was:

```
def mirrored(maxval, inc):
    x = np.arange(inc, maxval, inc)
    if x[-1] != maxval:
        x = np.r_[x, maxval]
    return np.r_[-x[::-1], 0, x]
```

but I am going to have to google a little more to understand *why* that works (also not sure if I want to round... the input for the increment might be legitimately specified to more than one decimal place)

Comment: The "divide neatly" bit is fraught with difficulty, given the inexact nature of floating point maths (for example, `0.3 * 3 != 0.9`).

Comment: Yes this too is a problem. But reasonable precision is OK here. I'm quite willing to accept 0.2999999998 ~= 0.3 for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be strictly mirrored around `0`, (i.e. always include 0 and the endpoints, and be perfectly symmetric about 0) you'll need a couple of steps.

First off, be aware of @NPE's comment above. Floating point math is not the same as decimal math!! This may seem beside the point, but it *will* bite you in certain circumstances.

There's more than one way to do this. Do you want to have all of the numbers be evenly spaced, or stick to the increment and only violate it at the endpoints?. This approach takes the latter of the two.

```
import numpy as np

def mirrored(maxval, inc=1):
    x = np.arange(inc, maxval, inc)
    if x[-1] != maxval:
        x = np.r_[x, maxval]
    return np.r_[-x[::-1], 0, x]

print mirrored(1, 0.3)
```

This yields:

```
[-1.  -0.9 -0.6 -0.3  0.   0.3  0.6  0.9  1. ]
```

If you want all of the numbers to be evenly spaced (but not the exact increment you specify), just use linspace:

```
import numpy as np

def mirrored2(maxval, inc=1):
    return np.linspace(-maxval, maxval, 2*maxval // inc)

print mirrored2(1, 0.3)
```

This yields:

```
[-1.  -0.6 -0.2  0.2  0.6  1. ]
```

Comment: Yes! Joe gets it. Everyone else seemed to miss the point that it must hit zero exactly (or as exactly as floats allow) and can only violate the increments at endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy using [`numpy.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> max_val = 100
>>> increment = 1
>>> a = np.arange(start=-max_val, stop=max_val+increment, step=increment)
>>> print a
array([-100,  -99,  -98,  -97,  -96,  -95,  -94,  -93,  -92,  -91,  -90,
    -89,  -88,  -87,  -86,  -85,  -84,  -83,  -82,  -81,  -80,  -79,
    -78,  -77,  -76,  -75,  -74,  -73,  -72,  -71,  -70,  -69,  -68,
    -67,  -66,  -65,  -64,  -63,  -62,  -61,  -60,  -59,  -58,  -57,
    -56,  -55,  -54,  -53,  -52,  -51,  -50,  -49,  -48,  -47,  -46,
    -45,  -44,  -43,  -42,  -41,  -40,  -39,  -38,  -37,  -36,  -35,
    -34,  -33,  -32,  -31,  -30,  -29,  -28,  -27,  -26,  -25,  -24,
    -23,  -22,  -21,  -20,  -19,  -18,  -17,  -16,  -15,  -14,  -13,
    -12,  -11,  -10,   -9,   -8,   -7,   -6,   -5,   -4,   -3,   -2,
     -1,    0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,
     10,   11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,
     21,   22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31,
     32,   33,   34,   35,   36,   37,   38,   39,   40,   41,   42,
     43,   44,   45,   46,   47,   48,   49,   50,   51,   52,   53,
     54,   55,   56,   57,   58,   59,   60,   61,   62,   63,   64,
     65,   66,   67,   68,   69,   70,   71,   72,   73,   74,   75,
     76,   77,   78,   79,   80,   81,   82,   83,   84,   85,   86,
     87,   88,   89,   90,   91,   92,   93,   94,   95,   96,   97,
     98,   99,  100])
```

In cases the increment value will be less than zero such as `max_val = 1` and `increment = 0.3`

The output will be:

```
[-1.  -0.7 -0.4 -0.1  0.2  0.5  0.8  1.1]
```

One way to solve this problem could be:

```
>>> print a[np.where((a<=max_val) & (a>=-max_val))[0]]
[-1.  -0.7 -0.4 -0.1  0.2  0.5  0.8]
```

Which ensures that the maximum and minimum values will be inside limits.

Comment: +1 On a side note, it's worth mentioning that `arange` accepts increments less than one, and doing `stop=max_val + 1` is incorrect in that case. (You'll have values above `max_val`.) To make it fully general, you'd want to do `stop=max_val + increment`.

Comment: Sadly, nope. Try that with max = 1, inc = 0.3

Comment: I have corrected the answer. Joe your solution doesn't work in all cases, the only way I found to deal with that situation is by using `np.where` function.

Answer (score 1):

Pure python, without nympy:

```
def mirror(max, step):
    i = -max
    while i<= max:
        yield i
        i += step

print list(mirror(5, 0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple code could work too. Not a bunch of 'defs', 'fors' and 'whiles'. Try it.

Obs: I wrote it by 10 to 10 to not have a extensive result. If you need one by one number from 1 to 100, remove the ',10' in the first line.

```
onehundred = list(range(0,101,10))
onehundred.reverse()
mirror = onehundred + list(reversed(onehundred))
print(mirror)
```

Answer (score -1):

This works, but the values of the resulting list need to be rounded:

```
def mirror_list(max, increment):
        lst = [-max]
        while lst[-1] < max:
            lst.append(lst[-1] + increment)
        lst[-1] = max
        return lst
```

You can get a rounded list like so:

```
lst = map(lambda x: round(x, 1), mirror_list(max=100, increment=0.2))
```

Comment: Carefully check if it will work for all inputs. Hint: Try the ones from the original question.